# Python Socket/Threads Sending Files From Server To Client

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, sockets, python-sockets

I'm working on a project with Python (Sockets/Threads), and a part of it say that i need to click on a button, choose a file from the server and send it to a client (I still didn't create the page and the button)
I'm trying to do it first with the cmd commands before going to the website + button !
The thing is, i wrote a cmd server/client code that allows me to control the client cmd (As if i'm doing it with a website buttons), let me explain !
As you can see in the first picture, the server can list the active clients "Clients", and choose which one he want to connect to "Select 0"
[Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGBe0.png)
Once connected i can send commands and the client execute them as you can see in the second picture
[Client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4KGm.png)
Everything is working fine, but i tried to add another function that sends a file when i type the command "Send" once i'm connected to a client, just a command like "Clients" and "Select 0" in the pictures above.
The problem is, even if i type "Send" in the server cmd, it doesn't work and it says : "Error sending the command !", the tryy except (execpt message)
[Send not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfwEq.png)
I will link pictures of the important functions for you to try and understand what i am trying to do :
In Summary : 1 - I want to send a command "Send" From Server, that send a file to the client
2 - I want the client to read the send command and get the file from the server
Thanks !
Server Code :
functions that list all the clients connected and select the client we want to connect to and send commands/files :
[Clients/Select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrBxG.png)
functions that send commands and files to the client (i don't know how it's to supposed to know to which client it has to send files)
[send commands/files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/793ma.png)
Client Code :
Lastly, the functions that get the files and commands and execute them
[executeCommands/getFiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKBz3.png)

SERVER CODE :(AS TEXT)

```
theSocket = socket.socket()
theSocket.bind((host,port))
connection,address = theSocket.accept()

#Display all the current active connections
def listConnections() :
    resultsData = ""

    #Check if a connection is still active or ont
    for isUnactive, aConnection in enumerate(connectionsList) :
        try :
            #Send string test
            aConnection.send(str.encode(" "))
            aConnection.recv(201480)

        except :
            #Delete if not active
            del connectionsList[isUnactive]
            del addressesList[isUnactive]
            continue

        resultsData = str(isUnactive) + " " + str(addressesList[isUnactive][0]) + " " + str(addressesList[isUnactive][1]) + "\n"

    print("----- Clients -----" + "\n" + resultsData)

#Choose a client target to connect to
def getTarget(cmd) :
    try :
        #Choose a client
        targetChosen = cmd.replace("Select ", "")
        targetChosen = int(targetChosen)

        #Connect to the the chosen client
        connection = connectionsList[targetChosen]
        print("You are now connected to : " + str(addressesList[targetChosen][0]))
        print(str(addressesList[targetChosen][0]) + "> ", end="")
        return connection

        '''
        Something like :
            173.249.21.59> Echo Hey
                Hey
        '''

    except :
        print("Selection not valid !")
        return listConnections()

#Send commands to the chosen client
def sendTargetCommands(connection) :
    while True :
        try :
            cmd = input()

            if cmd == "Quit" :
                break
        
            if cmd == "Send" :
                sendFile()

            #Send the command to the client
            if len(str.encode(cmd)) > 0 :
                connection.send(str.encode(cmd))
                clientResponse = str(connection.recv(1024), "utf-8")
                print(clientResponse, end="")

        except :
            print("Error sending the command !")
            break

def sendFile() :
    #Opening the file to send
    fileSending = open("Profiles.txt", 'rb')

    #Reading the file to send
    dataFile = fileSending.read()

    #Sending the file
    theSocket.send(fileSending.encode("utf-8"))

    #Sending the file data
    theSocket.send(dataFile.encode("utf-8"))

    #Closing the file
    fileSending.close()
```

CLIENT CODE : (AS TEXT)

```
theSocket.connect((host,port))

if theSocket :
    print("Connected to the server successfull !")

#Trying to get the files and save them
def recieveFile ():
    print("Receiving files ...")
    fileName = theSocket.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
    print("fileName Received !")    
    fileData = open(fileName, "wb")
    print("fileData Written !")
    dataFile = theSocket.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
    print("dataFile Received !")
    fileData.write(dataFile)
    print("dataFile Written !")
    fileData.close()
    print("fileData Closed !")

def commandsReceiving() :
    while True :
        print("Receiving commands ...")
        dataReceiver = theSocket.recv(1024)
        if dataReceiver[:2].decode("utf-8") == 'cd':
            os.chdir(dataReceiver[3:].decode("utf-8"))
        
        #If the command from the server is "Send" call the function above and try to get the files
        if dataReceiver.decode("utf-8") == "Send" :
            recieveFile()

        if len(dataReceiver) > 0 :
            cmd = subprocess.Popen(dataReceiver[:].decode("utf-8"),shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
            outputByte = cmd.stdout.read() + cmd.stderr.read()
            outputString = str(outputByte, "utf-8")
            currentDirectory = os.getcwd() + "> "
            theSocket.send(str.encode(outputString + currentDirectory))
            
            #If you want to show what you are writing in both computers
            print(outputString)

commandsReceiving()
```

Thanks for your help <3 !

Comment: Please send your code and error-outputs as text instead of pictures.
It would be much easier for people to help. You should also try and structure your text a bit.

Comment: @Soufiane El Himani. Comment out thesocket.send(filesending.

Comment: @thamuppet Hope it's better now.

Comment: @toyotaSupra Still goes to the except side : "Error sending the command !" It doens't go to the try and call the function sendFile()

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.